# IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager

Tags: android

Что-то никак не пойму в чем дело... 
Подгружаю данные порциями и вывожу списком. Если при подгрузке данных сменить ориентацию экрана, то вылезает вот такой exception "IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager". 
Как избавиться от этого?

И еще один вопрос: подгрузив очередную порцию данных, меняю ориентацию экрана и тут все подгруженные данные пропадают и список начинает грузиться заново, с самого начала.

---

```
    class NetWork extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected ProgressDialog proDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        proDialog = new ProgressDialog(EngineBrowseByOnline.this);
        proDialog.setMessage("Loading search engines...");
        proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proDialog.setCancelable(true);
        proDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        rsj = new ReadStringJson(SERVER_URL + SERVER_PATH_1 + "from=" + (from+1) + "&number=" + number + SERVER_PATH_2 + GROUP);
        try {
            // здесь идет парсинг json и заполнение names,
            // descriptions и logoUrl
            parsingData(rsj.readFromServer());  
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             Log.e("IOException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
             Log.e("JSONException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter.addEnginesNames(names);
        adapter.addEnginesDescriptions(descriptions);
        adapter.addEnginesLogoUrl(logoUrl);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        proDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: матчасть пробовал читать? при перевороте полносью перерисовывается активити, старые потоки продолжают работать, новые запускаются заново и еще много интересного происходит :)

Comment: читать пробовал, только не понял как решить проблему...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала было бы не плохо увидеть код.

Когда меняешь ориентацию вызывается **onPause()/OnResume()**, или o **onPause()/onStop()/onResume()/onRestart()/onStart()/onResume()** - это и приводит к перезагрузки всего контента. Обойти это можно через сохранение промежуточных данных в **Bundle savedInstanceState** - заметем так же что это единственный аргумент onCreate(). На самом деле нужно еще теории, но лучше самому почитать первоисточник [первоисточник](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: Добавил код. Источник этот читал, только что-то не очень помогло..

Answer (score 0):

Вот статься хорошая, почитай на досуге [как работать с потоками и не терять связи с ними.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html)

**PS**

еще как вариант посоветовал бы в манифесте для активности указать **configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**. Это говорит о том, что всякие изменения размера экрана или его поворот ты будешь отлавливать сам, при этом при этих изменениях активность не будет заного пересоздаваться.

**НО:**

есть волшебные аппаратики, на которых и такие вещи не срабатывают. тогда на помощь приходит статья, про которую я написал выше.